# call web service with alamofire Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, alamofire

How to call this kind of Web Service with `alamofire`.

```
http://www.example.com?abcrequest={"abc":"abc"}

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
                 println(json)
                 println(error)
              })
```

So what should I passed in URL and in parameter?

Comment: I don't understand the question whatsoever

Comment: Are you asking how to get the parameters formatted as JSON?